# Assigning value to an unsigned int *

Tags: c

I have the following struct defined

```
struct ComputeData{
  unsigned int * temperatureRawBuf;
  unsigned int * bloodPressRawBuf;
  unsigned int * pulseRateRawBuf;
  unsigned int * tempCorrectedBuf;
  unsigned int * bloodPressCorrectedBuf;
  unsigned int * prCorrectedBuf;
  unsigned short int * measurementSelection;
};
typedef struct ComputeData ComputeData;
```

In my main file i have the following

```
  unsigned int temperatureRaw [8] = {75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75};

  unsigned int bloodPressRaw [16] = {80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80};

  unsigned int pulseRateRaw [8] = {50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50};

  unsigned int tempCorrected [8] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

  unsigned int bloodPressCorrected [16] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} ;

  unsigned int prCorrected [8] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

  //create the TCB for Compute
  ComputeData * computeDataPtr;
  computeDataPtr = (struct ComputeData *) malloc(sizeof(struct ComputeData));
  //assign compute data locals to point to the values declared at the top
  computeDataPtr->temperatureRawBuf = &temperatureRaw[0];
  computeDataPtr->bloodPressRawBuf = &bloodPressRaw[0];
  computeDataPtr->pulseRateRawBuf = &pulseRateRaw[0];
  print("Test2"); //pseudocode for print

  computeDataPtr->tempCorrectedBuf = &tempCorrected[0];
  computeDataPtr->bloodPressCorrectedBuf = &bloodPressCorrected[0];
  computeDataPtr->prCorrectedBuf = &prCorrected[0];
  print("Hello"); //pseudocode here for print
```

**Edit:**

I have re-edited the question, with more detailed code

If i comment out the code after the first print, the value of "Test2" gets printed. But once I uncomment out the code beneath the first print program just fails to print any of the values.

Comment: `value` is not assigned first.

Comment: @aschepler it seems to compile

Comment: Tip: `typedef struct Random Random` is better than `typedef struct Random random`. The types are now consistently uppercase, and `random` is available for the name of a variable of type `Random` or `struct Random`.

Answer (score 3):

The assignment of `value->abc` itself is valid code, but in order for it to succeed the `value` must be assigned to point to a valid instance of `random`, for example

```
random storage;
random *value = &storage;
value->abc = arr;
```

or

```
random *value = malloc(sizeof(random));
value->abc = arr;
```

Note that if `arr` is a local array, using a pointer to it past the end of scope of `arr` itself would be undefined behavior. If you plan to extend life of `arr`, for example, by returning `value` from a function, you need to `malloc` the array as well:

```
random *value = malloc(sizeof(random));
value->abc = malloc(7 * sizeof(unsigned int));
memcpy(value->abc, arr, 7 * sizeof(unsigned int));
```

Comment: i tried your second suggestion and still  seem to face the issue

Comment: Is the assignment itself valid code? `arr` is an array of pointers, not an array of unsigned ints.

Comment: sorry that was a typo on my end it is defined as unsigned int arr[7]

Comment: @RRP Assuming that there's no other code and there are no additional members, the assignment should work fine.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight still facing the issue going to reedit for more details

Answer (score 0):

You didn't allocate any memory, you just created a pointer. Where is your pointer pointing to?

What you probably want to do instead is:

```
random value;
random.abc = arr;
```